# Better keyboard shortcuts

Tags: 16.04, shortcut-keys

I'd like to press, for example, the Menu key and the output be as if I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> or another combination of keys. In other words, I'd like to set aliases for combos using the same graphical user interface (System Settings/Keyboard menu) provided by Ubuntu 16.04 to set/change keyboard shortcuts. Thanks in advance!

LE: I do not want to install Autokey, I want a builtin functionality as I already mentioned above. In plus, Ctrl+R does one thing inside a browser window and another thing inside a terminal window. I just want, for example, to press Menu key and Ubuntu to think I pressed Ctrl+R. That's all. I hope I was clear enough. Just a suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

If you like to change the keyboard shortcuts of various operations then you can do it through settings.
Please follow the following steps.

1. Go to the system settings.
2. Click on "text entry."
3. Now go to the bottom right corner of the dialogue box and click on "keyboard settings."
4. There you will find the list of various shortcuts and what they do.
5. You can change the shortcuts from here.